# hay, doesn't $LaTeX$ math markup work here at prog.se?

Tags: feature-request

boy, it would be lame if it doesn't.

can you guys find out what the physics.se and dsp.se do to get math markup?

just curious.

Comment: Related: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6154/40980